# Trying to install with composer makes an error

Tags: ssh, plesk

When trying to install a php package with composer I just get the error that user/bin/env: 'php' : no such file or directory

On my Plesk server I open the SSH terminal and navigate to the right directory and enter this: composer require stichoza/google-translate-php

I expected it to install Google Translate PHP, but I just get the error.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not a script error. You try to run composer from the chrooted environment or without the full path prefix to PHP, for that reason PHP is not found. Within the chrooted environment (SSH chrooted in Plesk Hosting Settings) this will not work at all. On a normal SSH shell it will work if you run PHP and the composer.phar with it like

on CentOS/RHEL:

```
/opt/plesk/php/X.X/bin/php /usr/lib64/plesk-9.0/composer.phar [options] [arguments]
```

or on Debian/Ubuntu:

```
/opt/plesk/php/X.X/bin/php /usr/lib/plesk-9.0/composer.phar [options] [arguments]
```

More can be found here: https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/12377596215703-How-to-run-Composer-with-Plesk-PHP